# How to create and update AB OTA zip for rockchip AOSP11(android11) ROM?

Tags: android-source, android-11, ota

I trying create AP OTA zip file on AOSP11 in (android11) for ROCchip.

Cloned source code from https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4/rockpi-android11 and copied the source code.

would like someone to let me know How to create AB OTA zip file.
Ideally give me valuable tips such as references, or step-by-step guide for that if it's possible. My ROM is based on Android 11.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to create A/B OTA, but not normal OTA. You can check whether a/b is enabled by "adb shell getprop ro.build.ab_update". If A/B is disabled in rockpi-android11, it's difficult to enable A/B.  To enable A/B, you should change the partition layout to enable A/B, and set AB_OTA_UPDATER to true, and ...

Comment: it seems not enabled. Empty response is coming ,when I ran "adb shell getprop ro.build.ab_update" command.Could you please share any docs or tips to enable A/B OTA  and  AB_OTA_UPDATER is true in /device.../BoardConfig.mk

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab

Comment: commented "BOARD_RECOVERYIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE","BOARD_CACHEIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE" and "BOARD_CACHEIMAGE_FILE_SYSTEM_TYPE" in my source code. But getting compilation errors. en/RECOVERY/resource.img: No such file or directory